# Load ViewController from a Cocoa Touch Framework in a Storyboard of another project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, xcode6

**EDIT:**

I found the solution. I was using Cocoapods in my framework to include some libraries. After removed Cocoapods, build again my framework, all works fine!
So, I need to include directly the libs without using Cocoapods in my framework...
Maybe do you know to use Cocoapods inside de framework ? Or maybe it's not the good way... ?

Thank you anyway ;)

---

I try to instantiate some view controllers in a Storyboard.

The thing is: I created a Cocoa Touch Frameworks with some view controllers.
I builded the Cocoa Touch Framework, and all are succeed.
I set some header files to "Public".

I created another XCode Project (my App). In this project, I imported my Cocoa Touche Framework. I have access to the view controllers inside my Cocoa Touch Frame in code, but when I try to load a view controller from my Storyboard with a view controller class of my Cocoa Touch Framework, I have the following warning in the consol:

```
2015-03-26 14:16:50.913 Myapp[6181:877062] Unknown class HomeViewController in Interface Builder file.
```

I tried many many things, like add "-all_load" and "-Objc" linker flags, set header files in public, etc. But still get this warning.

How can I load ViewController class in a Cocoa Touch Framework in a XCode Project in a Storyboard ?

Thank you for help,
Best regards.